# $\mathsf{AC}_\mathsf{WO}+\mathsf{AC}^\mathsf{WO}\Rightarrow \mathsf{AC}$?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, independence-results

Let

> $\mathsf{AC}_\mathsf{WO}$: Every well-orderable family of non-empty sets has a choice function.
>
> $\mathsf{AC}^\mathsf{WO}$: Every family of non-empty well-orderable sets has a choice function.

My questions are:

- Does $\mathsf{ZF}+\mathsf{AC}_\mathsf{WO}+\mathsf{AC}^\mathsf{WO}$ prove $\mathsf{DC}_{\omega_1}$?
- Does $\mathsf{ZF}+\mathsf{AC}_\mathsf{WO}+\mathsf{AC}^\mathsf{WO}$ prove $\mathsf{AC}$?

I've searched in Howard and Rubin's [*Consequences of the Axiom of Choice*](https://doi.org/10.1090/surv/059) without success. For sure both $\mathsf{AC}_\mathsf{WO}$ and $\mathsf{AC}^\mathsf{WO}$ do not imply $\mathsf{AC}$, more specifically $\mathsf{AC}_\mathsf{WO}$ doesn't prove $\mathsf{DC}_{\omega_1}$ and $\mathsf{AC}^\mathsf{WO}$ doesn't even prove $\mathsf{AC}_\omega(\mathbb{R})$.
Do you have an idea?

EDIT: In *Howard, Paul; Rubin, Jean E.*, [**The axiom of choice for well-ordered families and for families of well-orderable sets**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2275876), it is proven that we cannot find a Fraenkel–Mostowski model witnessing such an independence. According to the authors, it is an open problem (unless some progress has been made in the mean time).

Comment: I don't have an example or proof off hand, but I'd be very surprised if the answer is positive.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Me too! But all the symmetric models I've seen in which $\mathsf{AC}^{WO}$ holds use finite supports and the least support property, whilst to have $\mathsf{AC}_{WO}$ we cannot use finite supports I think, at least in the usual à la Cohen way...

Comment: MathJax/LaTeX tip: `$\mathsf{ZF}+\mathsf{AC}_\mathsf{WO}+\mathsf{AC}^\mathsf{WO}$` looks exactly the same as `$\mathsf{ZF+AC_{WO}+AC^{WO}}$`.

Comment: Can you perhaps think of a single statement of the form “every <foo> family of non-empty <bar> sets” which would imply both $\mathsf{AC_{WO}}$ and $\mathsf{AC^{WO}}$ without obviously implying $\mathsf{AC}$ (even if non-implication isn't clear either)? That might be a start.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: Every function with well-orderable fibers or well-orderable image admits an inverse.

Comment: The problem with FM models here is that well-orderable is too strict of a notion, in a sense. Specifically, the power set of a well-orderable set is again well-orderable.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yeah, I'm thinking the same. I wonder if it wouldn't be too hard to prove AC in $\text{ZFA} + \text{AC}_{\text{WO}} + \text{AC}^{\text{WO}} + \text{WF} \models \text{AC}.$ (WF the well-founded kernel).

Comment: @ElliotGlazer: Isn't this the point of the Howard–Rubin paper mentioned in the edit?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The argument in that paper relies heavily on the permutation model structure. It doesn't give an argument for the claim I suggested.

Comment: @ElliotGlazer: I see. Good point.